# Php get hours difference ranges from midnight fails

Tags: php

Am trying to get hours from midnight from the current time

that is suppose now it's 02:34 then I expect to get

```
02:34 - 02:00,
01:00 - 02:00,
00:00 - 01:00
```

as an array

so I have tried

```
function getFromMidnight(){
    $durations = [];
    $currentTime = strtotime("now");
    $iStartOfHour = $currentTime - ($currentTime % 3600);
    $midnight = strtotime('today midnight');

    $hours = floor(($iStartOfHour - $midnight)/3600);
    array_push($durations,["from"=>$currentTime, "to"=>$iStartOfHour]);

    if(floor(($iStartOfHour - $midnight)/3600) > 0){
        for ($val = 1;$val <= $hours;$val++){
            $newval = $val +=1;
            array_push($durations, ["from"=>strtotime('- '.$val.' hours',$iStartOfHour),"to"=>strtotime('- '.$newval.' hours',$iStartOfHour)]);
        }
    }

    return $durations; 
    }
```

For the first array has the correct durations e.g. from the above example 02:34-02:00 but the next arrays are messed up giving me wrong values with constant timestamps eg: `01:00 - 01:00`

I suspect its my for loop with an error, what could be wrong?

Comment: maybe try using carbon, it may have already what are you looking for

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Php get time differences in dynamic way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52049000/php-get-time-differences-in-dynamic-way)

Comment: It would have been helpful if you had given this extra information when you first asked the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52049000/php-get-time-differences-in-dynamic-way/52049230#52049230)

Comment: This part of the code `$newval = $val += 1`. You're re-setting `$val`. Replace `+=` with `+`

Answer (score 1):

I would not use that code, instead of working things out just use [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php) inverted and work backwards. Then sub() the hour in the loop to get the offset.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

$begin = new DateTime('today midnight');
$end = new DateTime();

$interval = new DateInterval('PT60M');
$interval->invert = 1;
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

$range = [];
foreach ($daterange as $date){
    $range[] = [
        'from' => $date->format("H:i"),
        'to' => $date->sub($interval)->format("H:i")
    ];
}

print_r($range);
```

https://3v4l.org/BMSbI

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [from] => 00:00
            [to] => 01:00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [from] => 01:00
            [to] => 02:00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [from] => 02:00
            [to] => 03:00
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [from] => 03:00
            [to] => 04:00
        )

)
```